# why hough transform detects two lines while there is only one line

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, line

I would like to detect a line and extract its two ended points. The common approach is using the hough transform. Luckily there is a [sample](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) in OpenCV regarding is matter, therefore I've drawn a line whose two ended points `p1(100,200), p2(400,200)`. I thought the aforementioned method will provid me with only these points. My sample image is

[image]

the hough transform provides me with two images which are

[image]

[image]

For Canny filter,

[image]

In the code, it seems that there are two lines are detected. This explains why the red line is thicker which indicates the fact that there are two lines rather than one. When I print out the number of lines, it shows me two as follows

```
lines.size(): 2
p1:<99,201>  p2:<401,201>
lines.size(): 2
p1:<102,198>  p2:<398,198>
```

Why I'm getting two lines?

Comment: Depending on the witdth of the bins in the HoughSpace, not all pixels might be assigned to the line. Try wider/less bins.

Comment: are you using canny edge detection before houghLines? you should check that intermediate image how it looks like. gradient might produce one edge at each side of the thick line.

Comment: @Micka, yes the sample actually uses canny algorithm.

Comment: can you post the intermediate canny image?

Comment: @Micka, I've linked the entire code in my post. For canny, `Mat dst, cdst;
 Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);
 cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);`

Comment: I'm asking not for code but for the result (of canny)... I'm too lazy to reproduce it myself atm...

Comment: do you see that there in fact ARE two lines in the image that you provide to the houghLines method?

Comment: @Micka, yes you are right. How can I fix that?

Comment: instead of edge detection (canny) use a ridge-detection (afaik no implementation in opencv) or a thresholding method, maybe followed by a thinning algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

It might be due to the width of the bins in your HoughSpace.
You probably choose one of the default OpenCv functio, i.e.

`HoughLines(X, X, 1, CV_PI/180, X, X, X );`

The arguments that are not X define the width of the bins [see](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html).
There it says:

`rho : The resolution of the parameter r in pixels. We use 1 pixel.`

For the first argument and for the second:

`theta: The resolution of the parameter \theta in radians. We use 1 degree (CV_PI/180)`

I don't now the values you chose, but you might want to choose larger ones.

Comment: I've tried to change the one parameter but without luck.